# Python > O365 > Mailbox Query > how to filter by email category

Tags: python

I have managed to get queries working with O365 for normal fields like sender, flag etc but I can't figure out how to query a list field.

I have tried

```
query = mailbox.new_query().on_attribute('categories').contains('Expenses')
```

but this results in

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?%24top=30&%24filter=contains%28categories%2C+%27Expenses%27%29+and+createdDateTime+gt+2022-02-25T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00 | Error Message: Invalid filter clause
```

There seems to be an on_list_field method but I cant figure out how that should be used.

for example:

```
query = mailbox.new_query().on_list_field('categories').contains('Expenses')
```

results in

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?%24top=30&%24filter=contains%28fields%2Fcategories%2C+%27Expenses%27%29 | Error Message: Could not find a property named 'fields' on type 'microsoft.graph.message'.
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with collections, you have to use any (and set the operation accordingly):

```
query = mailbox.new_query().any(collection='categories', word='Expenses', operation='eq')
```